# Adding formula to a cell and referencing to variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a formula into a cell with variables from VBA, but I'm getting another `Application or Object defined error`. The error is triggered on the first row op `Range("R" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=Q" & i & "/" & DollarRate`. I have tried using just `Formula` instead of `FormulaR1C1`.

Columns Q and R are empty. Column Q will contain values in € and Column R will show the value in $.

```
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim DollarRate As Double

DollarRate = InputBox("Enter dollar rate:", "Dollar rate")

Range("Q1").Value = "$ POS"
Range("R1").Value = "€ POS"

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    Range("R" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=Q" & i & "/" & DollarRate
Next i
```

Comment: It should be `.Formula` not `.FormulaR1C1` since you're not using R1C1 notation but you could just use: `Range("R2:R" & lastrow).Formula = "=Q2/" & DollarRate` and skip the loop. It would be better to put the rate into a cell and simply refer to that in the formula though.

Comment: @Rory, I need the loop because I have 700 rows (in this case) and each row in the Q column can have a different value. So I need the loop. Like I said, I also tried using `Formula`instead , but I get the same error ..

Comment: Your loop is putting the same formula into every cell so it is unnecessary. Is your worksheet protected? What does `Msgbox Dollarrate` show exactly?

Comment: @Rory, I want each cell in the R column to contain the formula `=Q(number)/(dollar rate)`. DollarRate contains `1,20` and is listed as double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    Range("R" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=Q" & i & "/" & DollarRate
Next i
```

with this:

```
Range("R2:R" & lastrow).FormulaLocal = "=Q2/" & DollarRate
```

Comment: Works great! I have no clue though how the cell number changes :P

Comment: It's because the row number is relative. It's the same as manually selecting all the cells, typing the formula for the first row and then pressing Ctrl+Enter.

Comment: oooh ok thanks! Just a question, do you know how you add text to it? Say `IF(I2="Yes";"You said yes";"No")`

Comment: Double the quotes up within the formula: `Range("R2:R" & lastrow).FormulaLocal = "IF(I2=""Yes"";""You said yes"";""No"")"`